# A ListView of two ListView builders

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I'm cloning a social media app design where there are two ListView: an horizontal one for the user stories, and a vertical one for user posts. I've already built them and they work, but I would like to wrap them in a unique ListView with stories at the top, and posts under the stories. If I scroll, the stories should disappear after a while and I should see only posts. How can I do?

UserStory widget:

```
class UserStory extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserStory({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: ListView.builder(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Container(
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

UserPost widget:

```
class UserPost extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserPost({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  leading: Container(
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade200
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: const Text("Ava Sadie"),
                  subtitle: Text("Sylhet, Bangladesh", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelSmall,),
                  trailing: IconButton(splashRadius: 20.0, onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.more_horiz_outlined),),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 250,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 5),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(splashRadius: 20.0, onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_outline,),),
                        Text("6.2k", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displaySmall,),
                      ],
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(width: 20,),

                    Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(splashRadius: 20.0, onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.messenger_outline,),),
                        Text("2.1k", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displaySmall,),
                      ],
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(width: 20,),

                    Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(splashRadius: 20.0, onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_border_outlined),),
                        Text("3.5k", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displaySmall,),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

HomePage:

```
import 'package:atlas/pages/widgets/user_post.dart';
import 'package:atlas/pages/widgets/user_story.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        forceMaterialTransparency: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: const Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          UserStory(),
          UserPost(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to wrap the body in a ListView, but it spams some errors and I see neither Stories nor posts

You find two photos of the actual screen, When opening homepage:

[image]

here it's all ok, but when I want to scroll stories should disappear and I should see only posts. Instead, as you can see in the second photo, stories stay at the top.

Second photo while scrolling:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace `Column` to `ListView` at **HomePage**.

```dart
body: ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    UserStory(),
    UserPost(),
  ],
),
```

And add `shrinkWrap: true` to `ListView` at **UserPost** widget.

```dart
return ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  ...,
);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! I had already done like that before but I hadn't set shrinkWrap to true, thanks!

Comment: Pleasure. If you are interested in performance of listview, you could use refer to Zakaria Hossain's answer. Also it's good to watch official video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUqDNnv_dh0&t=1s).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `CustomScrollView` with `SliverList` and `SliverToBoxAdapter` like the below code or use `shrinkWrap: true` to `ListView at UserPost`:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        forceMaterialTransparency: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: UserStory()),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SizedBox(height: 10)), // Spacer between story and posts
          SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return UserPost();
            },
            childCount: 10, // Replace this with the actual number of posts
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use SliverAppBar search for it and you will find what your request

Answer (score 0):

You can make below changes and it will work:

Removing the Expanded from UserPost and making, making true the `shrinkWrap` Property of `ListView.builder`

```
 ListView.builder(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          /// Your UserPost Code.
        }
 )
```

And Replace the `Column` widget with `ListView` widget in the home screen.

```
  body: ListView(
    children: const [
      UserStory(),
      UserPost()
    ],
  )
```

More on you can also remove the `Column` widget from the `UserStory` as i don't i see any use of it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [NotificationListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html) to listen for the position of your scrollable widget. Try this method:

```
import 'package:atlas/pages/widgets/user_post.dart';
import 'package:atlas/pages/widgets/user_story.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool showStory = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width= MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        forceMaterialTransparency: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        height: height,
        width: width,
        child: NotificationListener<ScrollEndNotification>(
          onNotification: (scrollState) {
            double currentPixel = scrollState.metrics.pixels;/// The current scroll position, in logical pixels along the vertical axis
            double maxPixel = scrollState.metrics.maxScrollExtent;  /// This value is typically greater than or equal to [minScrollExtent]. It can be infinity, if the scroll is unbounded.
            double minPixel = scrollState.metrics.minScrollExtent;
            if (currentPixel + 5.0 == maxPixel) {
              setState((){ showStory=false; });///Hide the story widget
            } else if (currentPixel - 5.0 == minPixel) {
              setState((){ showStory=false; });///Shows the story widget
            }
            return false;
          },
          
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
shrinkWrap:true,
            children: [
              Visibility(
                child:   UserStory(), //Visible only on when showStory is true
                visible: showStory==true,
              ),
              UserPost(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Play with `currentPixel` to set where to make story to disapear.